# Conditional Probability in a game of best of 5

Tags: probability

There is a basketball game which is a best of five.Series between two teams each with 50% chance of winning.
The Tigers and the lions
Find the probability that the series is won by the tigers in game 5

Answer (score 3):

First, we calculate the probability that there even *is* a fifth game. That means that the Tigers have two wins and two losses by the end of the fourth game. This can happen in six different ways:
$$
WWLL, WLWL, WLLW, LWWL, LWLW, LLWW
$$
(where $W$ stands for win, $L$ stands for loss). Every single one of those possibilities has probability $0.5^4$ to happen. That means that the probability of a fifth game taking place is
$$
6\cdot 0.5^4 = 37.5\%
$$
Now that we know that there is a $37.5\%$ chance of reaching the fifth game, and the Tigers and the Lions have even odds of winning that game, you should have your answer.

Comment: I think I've got a different result. Can you please have a look?

Comment: Your answers are the same. Read the last lines of Arthur's answer again.

Comment: @EricS.: Yep, I had a feeling that "think" was for a good reason :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $1$ denote Tigers win and $0$ denote Tigers lose:

- $\color\red  {P(000  )=\frac{1}{2^3}}$
- $\color\red  {P(111  )=\frac{1}{2^3}}$
- $\color\red  {P(1000 )=\frac{1}{2^4}}$
- $\color\red  {P(0100 )=\frac{1}{2^4}}$
- $\color\red  {P(0010 )=\frac{1}{2^4}}$
- $\color\red  {P(0111 )=\frac{1}{2^4}}$
- $\color\red  {P(1011 )=\frac{1}{2^4}}$
- $\color\red  {P(1101 )=\frac{1}{2^4}}$
- $\color\red  {P(11000)=\frac{1}{2^5}}$
- $\color\red  {P(10100)=\frac{1}{2^5}}$
- $\color\red  {P(10010)=\frac{1}{2^5}}$
- $\color\red  {P(01100)=\frac{1}{2^5}}$
- $\color\red  {P(01010)=\frac{1}{2^5}}$
- $\color\red  {P(00110)=\frac{1}{2^5}}$
- $\color\green{P(00111)=\frac{1}{2^5}}$
- $\color\green{P(01011)=\frac{1}{2^5}}$
- $\color\green{P(01101)=\frac{1}{2^5}}$
- $\color\green{P(10011)=\frac{1}{2^5}}$
- $\color\green{P(10101)=\frac{1}{2^5}}$
- $\color\green{P(11001)=\frac{1}{2^5}}$

Hence the probability that Tigers win the series on game #$5$ is:

$$\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^5}=18.75\%$$

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there are $2^5 = 32$ possible outcomes.

The only variations where Tigers win on match 5 is where we pick exactly 2 out of the first 4 matches where Lions win: $4 \choose 2$.

Probability is the division of the two.